# How to check whether the system is supported by Qt5?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I want to run a PyQt5 application on different systems. When it's run on a system that is supported by Qt5, everything is fine. Otherwise, I want to switch to a text-based interface automatically.

When I try to start the app in a wrong environment (e.g., via an SSH for a test), I get the following errors:

```
qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display 
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, wayland-egl, wayland, wayland-xcomposite-egl, wayland-xcomposite-glx, webgl, xcb.

Aborted (core dumped)
```

Unfortunately, the app crashes leaving me no way to use `try ... except` block. Is there any way to check the compatibility and avoid the crash?

A minimal example of a PyQt5 app is the following:

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
QApplication([])  # this line leads to crash as described above
```

The only use of it is that it crashed under curtain circumstances.

---

*For future me.*

For now, the solution is

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import subprocess

    child = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, '-c',
                              'from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication; QApplication([])'],
                             stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    child.wait()
    ret_code = child.returncode
    if ret_code == 0:
        gui.run()  # load the GUI
    else:
        print('This platform is not supported by Qt5')
```

Comment: You might want to look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63594235/c-detect-if-display-is-connected-avoiding-gtk-warning-cannot-open-display).

Comment: @G.M., thanks. It might cover most of the cases. However, I'd like to know whether Qt5 has a plugin for the current system, not just a display. For the moment, I start another process of Python executing the minimal example with `subprocess` and check for the exit code.

Comment: @StSav012 execute `QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS="1" python your_script.py`

Comment: @eyllanesc, how should it help? I see lots of lines. Some of them mention `QFactoryLoader` that I can't access from Python. The lines don't even specify why `xcb` plugin is preferred despite others are found and provide their keys.

Answer (score -1):

```
/home/User/.local/lib/python3.x/site-packages/cv2
```

delete this file

opencv is a library by itself Here, when you want to use it with qt, it causes conflicts in libraries.
i got this problem too much and i solve it with this method

Comment: You should provide an explanation. How does this fix the problem? How does deleting a cv2 file answer the question "*Is there any way to check the compatibility and avoid the crash?*".

Comment: opencv is a library by itself

Here, when you want to use it with qt, it causes conflicts in libraries.

Comment: i got this problem too much and i solve it with this method

Comment: Please use the [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69541544/edit) link under your answer to put your explanation _in the answer itself_. In the future, make sure to _always_ provide explanations for answers.

Comment: What does OpenCV have to do with PyQt5? I get it that is might conflict with PyQt5, but it should be at least installed for that. In my case, I need to switch between a GUI and a text-based interface, depending on the GUI support.

Comment: I don't know the exact explanation.but if you write your error exactly, on the first line it says which library it conflicts with. it works when remove the conflicting file,it works for me to delete the file mentioned in the error output